# Soundboard button issue

Tags: windows, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have this code

```
private void PlayAudioButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (SinatraMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
            {
                SinatraMediaElement.Stop();
            }
            SinatraMediaElement.Play();
        }
```

And this code

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Button Name="PlayAudioButton"

                    Height="100"

                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Background="Chocolate"
                    Click="PlayAudioButton_Click" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    >

                Buble
            </Button>

            <MediaElement x:Name="SinatraMediaElement"
                          Source="/Assets/Audio/sinatra.wav"
                          AutoPlay="False"
                          Volume="1"
                          />
```

My problem is that even though i've added

```
if (SinatraMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
            {
                SinatraMediaElement.Stop();
            }
```

it still doesn't stop the current playing sound on pressing another button..I just can't get it to work..any ideas? thank you

Comment: Did you try `SinatraMediaElement.Stop();` in some other button click event without having it within the play button event handler?

Comment: i don't think so..what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved,here is the fixed code for whoever faces the same problem as I did.

```
private void PlayAudioButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (BubleMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
            {
                SinatraMediaElement.Stop();
            }
            SinatraMediaElement.Play();
        }

        private void Play2AudioButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (SinatraMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
            {
                BubleMediaElement.Stop();
            }

            {
                BubleMediaElement.Play();
            }
```

code explanation : if buble sound is pressed then stop sinatra sound and if sinatra sound is pressed then stop buble sound. pretty easy *dumb me*. thank you stackoverflow community.